# Share event/data between all instances of custom Angular16 components

Tags: angular, angular16

I need to share event/data between *all* instances of `<my-component>`. So, if user selects certain date in one instance then other instances of the same component should validate selected date and only allow dates after.

```html
<div *ngFor="let parameter of parameterCollection">
  <my-component [p]="parameter" />
</div>
```

I tried shareable service of Subject observable, but it behaves like a single instance... I suspect my code isn't right.

Here's shareable service:

```js
@Injectable()
export class FilteringService {


  /// observable string sources
  private announceSource = new Subject<string>();

  /// observable string streams
  missionAnnounced = this.announceSource.asObservable();

  /// service message commands
  announceMission(mission: string) {
    this.announceSource.next(mission);
  }

}
```

Here's my component (*trimmed for brevity*):

```js
  constructor( private readonly _filteringSvc: FilteringService ) {
    _filteringSvc.missionAnnounced.subscribe( mission => {
      console.log('ANNOUNCED EVENT: ' + mission + ' for ' + this._parameterId);
    });
  }

  selectionChanged( newValue) {
    this._filteringSvc.announceMission( newValue);
  }
```

Comment: "I tried shareable service of Subject observable, but it behaves like a single instance" - are you perhaps looking for a mapping of `_parameterId` to selection? That is, a way to see the last value for each instance?

Comment: You might have different instances of the `FilteringService` as it is not provided in root. So it is possible that you are firing a value in one `Subject` but the components are subscribing to another one. In order to check that, can you : 1) add `id = Math.random()` as a field of `FilteringService` and 2) `console.log(_filteringSvc.id)` in your component ?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle is correct, you are using a different instance of the service, you could provide the service at the root level or at the same module of the components to share the same subject.

Comment: Arnaud, I tried your suggestion - the time is identical for both, event fired and event received. I also tried to add "providedIn: 'root'", but to the same results.  I'm not clear if I should expect ALL instances to receive the event or only one.

Comment: Oscar, where can I find how to provide service at the same module to share the Subject?

Comment: D M, "_parameterId" isn't an issue - my focus is that all instances receive the event.

Comment: Of course they all receive the same event; they're all subscribed to the same Subject. Am I misunderstanding "it behaves like a single instance"? It sounds to me like you have a singleton service/Subject and are trying to instead have a singleton service with a subject (or at least a value) per subscribed component.

Comment: Does "it behaves like a single instance" actually mean that you're seeing a new instance of your service per component?

Comment: "it behaves like a single instance" means I only see one event received message logged in console, when in fact there are multiple, to be exact 5 instances of this component.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Your code should work as-is. Here's a StackBlitz showing a `console.log` for each component: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bgmuup?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: D M, your stackblitz example works perfect though not any different than my code.  I guess there's some interference within my project - I'll try to find it.  Thank You very much!

Answer (score 0):

Change the Subject to BehaviorSubject, maybe that will help.

```
@Injectable()
export class FilteringService {


  /// observable string sources
  private announceSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

  /// observable string streams
  missionAnnounced = this.announceSource.asObservable();

  /// service message commands
  announceMission(mission: string) {
    this.announceSource.next(mission);
  }

}
```

Comment: I tried this approach too, but to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried removing "readonly" from the import in the constructor?
constructor( private _filteringSvc: FilteringService )

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine as it is, so I would assume the issue lies elsewhere.

Are you positive that the `selectionChanged()` method is being invoked as expected?